# how to throttle the scale out of an azure function

Tags: azure-functions

I have a blob-triggered azure function. For each new file added to the storage account, the function gets triggered, like the following:

```
<Storage Account> --> Azure Function --> Remote Http Call
```

**How do we limit the amount of concurrent Azure Functions that are spinned up?**

Perhaps we should be doing queue-triggered or different-trigger?

Comment: It is kind of doing the opposite of what Azure Functions are used for, isn't it?

Comment: nope it is not.

Answer (score 2):

The blob trigger uses a queue internally, so the maximum number of concurrent function invocations is controlled by the [queues configuration in host.json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-queue#host-json). 
The default settings limit concurrency to `24` invocations. This limit applies separately to each function that uses a blob trigger.

```
{
    "version": "2.0",
    "extensions": {
        "queues": {
            "maxPollingInterval": "00:00:02",
            "visibilityTimeout" : "00:00:30",
            "batchSize": 16,
            "maxDequeueCount": 5,
            "newBatchThreshold": 8
        }
    }
}
```

For more details, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob#trigger---concurrency-and-memory-usage).